# Changing icon style for primeNG p-panel

Tags: css, angular, panel, primeng

I have created a p-panel which is toggleable. As usual it has a button for expanding or collapsing it, but this icon acts as a button in the way that it gets selected when I click it.

I have disabled this property for buttons in css:

```
 button:focus {
    outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
 }
```

I want to disable this property also for the icons of the panel but I have no idea how to do it. I have read something about ng-deep so I figure out I must do something like

```
::ng-deep .p-panel .p-panel-titlebar-toggler {
  outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

That of course does not work.
I have no idea further than this, any help is welcome.

Edit: Adding the html snippet:

```
<p-panel [toggleable]="true" [toggler]="'header'" [(collapsed)]="panelFuncionalidades" >
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                Panel de funcionalidades
            </ng-template>
            Here are some buttons and stuff that go inside the panel


    </p-panel>
```

the variable PanelFuncionalidades is a bollean in order to open and close the panel from other places.

About the desired output I just want to remove the circle which appears around the "expand" or "collapse" buttons which appears when clicked as is shown in this image [image]

This circle disappers when you click outside it, but I want to avoid it appearing.

Comment: Can you please add the html snippet and also what's your expected output?

Comment: Added it, I hope it is clear. @MirentafazAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `CSS` in your styles.css file

```
.p-panel .p-panel-header .p-panel-header-icon:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Adding the working stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-panel-demo-13srhs?file=src%2Fstyles.css)